# Use SHGetFileInfo in Java with JNA

Tags: java, c#, winapi, jna

I tried to translate the SHGetFileInfo function from Shell32 into Java with JNA and used C# code and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetfileinfoa) as reference

While in the C# code psfi.iIcon is 432 in my translated Java code psfi.iIcon is 0. If I am right, for the same file they should be same no matter which language I use, shouldn't they?

My Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "[PATH_TO_EXE]\\test.exe"; //Of course in my code I used the real path

    SHFILEINFO sfi = new SHFILEINFO();
    DWORD_PTR i = Shell32.INSTANCE.SHGetFileInfo(path, 0, sfi, sfi.size(), SHGFI.SysIconIndex);

    System.out.println(sfi.iIcon); //<-- Prints 0, should print 432
}

public static class SHGFI {
    static final int SysIconIndex = 0x000004000;
    static final int LargeIcon = 0x000000000;
    static final int UseFileAttributes = 0x000000010;
}

public interface Shell32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    Shell32 INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary("shell32", Shell32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
    DWORD_PTR SHGetFileInfo(String pszPath, int dwFileAttributes, SHFILEINFO psfi, int cbFileInfo, int uFlags);
}

public static class SHFILEINFO extends Structure {
    public HICON hIcon;
    public int iIcon;
    public DWORD dwAttributes;
    public char[] szDisplayName = new char[260];
    public char[] szTypeName = new char[80];

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("hIcon", "iIcon", "dwAttributes", "szDisplayName", "szTypeName");
    }
}
```

Is there anything fundemental that I did wrong? I'm new to JNA and Windows functions

Comment: Have you tried using the SHGFI_ICON (0x000000100) flag? Just to see the behavior.

Comment: @LppEdd Same thing

Comment: That is pretty strange, are you sure you're pointing to the same resource?

Comment: Yep. Just an exe laying on my desktop

Comment: Are you executing this with administrator priviledges? Shouldn't be required, but worth giving a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the *Remarks* section, there is this piece of information, which imho might be the source of your problem

> You must initialize Component Object Model (COM) with `CoInitialize` or
>   `OleInitialize` prior to calling `SHGetFileInfo`.

It's a pretty straightforward call

```
CoInitialize(null);
```

---

As DanielWiddis pointed out in the comments, per documentation

> New applications should call `CoInitializeEx` instead of `CoInitialize`

And

> To close the COM library gracefully, each successful call to
>   `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx`, including those that return `S_FALSE`,
>   must be balanced by a corresponding call to `CoUninitialize`

Example

```
CoInitializeEx(null, 0);
CoUninitialize();
```

Comment: [Applications developed today should call `CoInitializeEx` rather than `CoInitialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coinitialize). Also don't forget to pair every `CoInitialize` call with a `CoUninitialize`!

Comment: @DanielWiddis thank you for the correction! Updated the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. For completeness you need a little bit more than that, though.  You should test the return value of `CoInitializeEx`.  `S_OK` and `S_FALSE` both mean COM was initialized successfully (and should be uninitialized after using it) but `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE` means it was already initialized with a different threading model and you need to switch the [threading flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objbase/ne-objbase-tagcoinit) from 0 (the default and what you specified) to 1 (if previously initialized) and try again.

Comment: (Which you mention citing the docs, other than the "retry" portion!)

Comment: @DanielWiddis I'm not sure if you can change the mode, some shell stuff requires STA.

Comment: @anders no, you can't change it if it's already been initialized in a different mode. Which is why `CoInitializeEx(null, 0);` could fail and return `RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`.  In this case, you would have to either (a) accept the failure/non-initialization and proceed, and trust the already initialized COM not to be shut down while you're using it, or (b) initialize yourself using the same mode as is already initialized, e.g., `CoInitializeEx(null, 1);` (which should return `S_FALSE`). This will ensure it will stay initialized for you.

Comment: @DanielWiddis What I meant was, I'm not sure if it is acceptable to use MTA. Some shell extensions might crash if they are not in a STA thread.

Comment: @Anders ah, I see that now on rereading.  In that case, however, the initialization will still fail (`RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`) and the user should *not* uninitialize... that's the key point.